# Does the SecKeychain API support iCloud Keychain synchronisation?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, icloud, keychain

According to Apple's documentation, I can create and access synchronised passwords from the OS X keychain using the so-called SecItem API when providing an additional `kSecAttrSynchronizable` attribute. The corresponding calls are `SecItemCopyMatching` or `SecItemAdd`.

Is it possible to read / write synchronised items as well in a legacy application that accesses the keychain via the SecKeychain API, for instance, using `SecKeychainSearchCreateFromAttributes`?

I have tried to specify the `kSecAttrSynchronizable` attribute in the call of `SecKeychainSearchCreateFromAttributes`, but got an error stating that there is no matching attribute.

Is it possible at all to access the iCloud keychain items via the SecKeychain API? And if, how must I specify the `kSecAttrSynchronizable` attribute in queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I posted the same question on the Apple developer forums, the straight answer I got was: "no".

Comment: Link to the Apple Dev Forums for reference: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/216498